# Null Constraint Violation Exception in MySQL 8.0.3 Update Query Despite Providing Value

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

**Question**:
I recently migrated my MySQL database from version 5.7 to 8.0.3, and I'm encountering an issue with null constraint violations during update queries. The database operates with strict mode off.

**Background**:
I have an insert query that inserts data with warnings due to missing required fields. The warning I'm receiving is "Error code: 1364 Field 'callback_received' doesn't have a default value." and that's expected because database is not running on strict mode so it's allowing insert data even with NULL.

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `order_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `order_code` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member_id` INT DEFAULT NULL, 
  `order_date` TIMESTAMP NULL, 
  `callback_received` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '1 - Yes  2 - No',
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`), 
  KEY `index_OrderCode` (`order_code`), 
  KEY `index_MemberID` (`member_id`) 
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

INSERT

```
INSERT INTO `order`(order_code,member_id,order_date) VALUES ('ORDCODE001',1000,NOW());
```

UPDATE

```
UPDATE `order`
SET `callback_received`=1 WHERE order_code = 'ORDCODE001'
```

Trigger
There is one trigger (order_generate_unique_code) which sets a unique order code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `order_generate_unique_code` BEFORE INSERT ON `order` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET new.order_code = get_unique_code(); END;  -- get_unique_code function having simple logic to generate unique string.
```

**Problem**:
Despite supplying a value in the update statement for 'callback_received', I'm encountering a null constraint error during execution:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'callback_received' cannot be null
```

I appreciate any insights into why this null constraint violation is occurring during the update, especially after the migration to MySQL 8.0.3.

Comment: The UPDATE statement you show does not set a value. Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: Also there are numerous syntax errors in your CREATE TABLE example, and I doubt you are using MySQL 8.0.3 (that was a beta release from 2017). It's important to be accurate when you post questions on Stack Overflow, to help readers understand the problem you are having. I don't mean to be disrespectful, but with so many mistakes in your post, can we trust what you say about your triggers? Perhaps they are in fact modifying the value to NULL.

Comment: Please construct your issue in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT) . Not related to the question I saw a lot of your questions with not accepted answers. Keep in mind that your questions-answers will help future readers as well.

Comment: @Suresh I can't reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/B9RX8L5w

Comment: Hi @ErgestBasha Thanks for your reply, Sorry for confusion, for callback_received there will no default value. On fiddle when i try to insert value without callback_received it's giving error, Field 'callback_received' doesn't have a default value, but on my database i am able to insert with warning.

Comment: @Suresh If you try MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8 versions in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2RXO8-yO) you will see that in 5.7 it works as this behavior is controlled by sql_mode strict off. In MySQL 8 it won't work because this `bug` is fixed and it should work as expected.  You should fix table design use enum data type like `callback_received enum('1','2') default NULL COMMENT '1 - Yes  2 - No',`  or change it to default null, my suggestion change it to tinyint default null https://dbfiddle.uk/pkBgLSoU

Comment: @ErgestBasha that is good input will go ahead and change to default null and also will validate sql_mode options.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0.3, in strict_mode the no_auto_value_on_zero is included by default.
So you would need to fix the update set part.
SET `callback_received` = 1 might fix it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).